# How to give pixel resolution to NetCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf

I am trying to create a NetCDF file in Python to dictate where to apply different rainfall time series. The dimensions of my study area are Y: 2000, X: 3000. I've tried using 1.667 and 10 for lats [:] and lons [:] which gives me an output, but the output I think is incorrect because when I open the nc file in GIS the pixel size is not -5,5 and the layer is not visible although the bands are present.
I've included the code, and the nc output properties as seen in GIS. If I swap all the dimensions I get a visible nc layer but with the incorrect dimensions.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import datetime

##https://towardsdatascience.com/create-netcdf-files-with-python-1d86829127dd

fn = r"H:/NETCDF/Amrie_NC/testufr.nc"
ds = nc.Dataset(fn, 'w', format='NETCDF4')
rainfile = r"H:/NETCDF/Amrie_NC/rain100.csv"
maskfile = r"H:/NETCDF/Amrie_NC/test_a.asc"

rf_loc_data = np.genfromtxt(rainfile,delimiter = ",")[:,1]
rf_dummy_data = np.genfromtxt(rainfile,delimiter = ",")[:,2]
mask_data = np.loadtxt(maskfile,skiprows=6)
mask_data = np.where(mask_data == -99999, 0, mask_data)

time = ds.createDimension('time', None)
lat = ds.createDimension('lat', 2000)
lon = ds.createDimension('lon', 3000)

lats = ds.createVariable('lat', 'float64', ('lat',))
lons = ds.createVariable('lon', 'float64', ('lon',))

#noaa NetCDF file format for lat/lon
lats.units = 'degrees_north'
lats.actual_range = [415000.0000000000000000,435000.0000000000000000]
lats.long_name = 'Latitude'
lats.actual_name = 'latitude'
lats.axis = 'Y'

lons.units = 'degrees_east'
lons.actual_range = [425000.0000000000000000,430000.0000000000000000]
#lons.actual_range = [178.17, 178.20]
lons.long_name = 'Longitude'
lons.actual_name = 'Longitude'
lons.axis = 'X'

lats[:] = np.arange(415000.0000000000000000,435000.0000000000000000, 10)
lons[:] = np.arange(425000.0000000000000000,430000.0000000000000000, 1.667)
#lons[:] = np.arange(178.171277329188, 178.201238, 0.0001066219969935890941)

##create time variables
##https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997314/write-times-in-netcdf-file
calendar = 'standard'
units = 'minutes since 1800-01-01 00:00:0.0'
##https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298054/generating-15-minute-time-interval-array-in-python
times = [datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15*x)
         for x in range(0,len(rf_loc_data))]
timevar32 = ds.createVariable(varname='time', dimensions=('time',),
                              datatype='float64')
#noaa NetCDF file format for time
timevar32.units = units
timevar32.long_name = 'Time'
timevar32.delta_t = '0000-01-00 00:00:00'
timevar32.avg_period = '0000-01-00 00:00:00'#
timevar32.standard_name = 'time'
timevar32.axis = 'T'
timevar32.actual_range = [1569072., 1947432.]

timevar32[:] = nc.date2num(times, units=units, calendar=calendar) 

value = ds.createVariable('percip', 'float32', ('time', 'lat', 'lon',))
value.units = 'mm/hr'
for i in range(0,len(rf_loc_data)):
    rain_val = rf_loc_data[i]
    rain_empty = rf_dummy_data[i]
    rain_apply = np.where(mask_data == 1, rain_val, mask_data)
    rain_split = np.where(rain_apply == 0, rain_empty, rain_apply)
    #rain_split = np.flipud(rain_split)
    value[i, :, :] = rain_apply

crs = ds.createVariable('spatial_ref', 'i4')
crs.spatial_ref='GCS_OSGB_1936",DATUM["D_OSGB_1936",SPHEROID["Airy_1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-100000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-2.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996012717],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'

ds.close()     `import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import datetime

##https://towardsdatascience.com/create-netcdf-files-with-python-1d86829127dd

fn = r"H:/NETCDF/Amrie_NC/testufr.nc"
ds = nc.Dataset(fn, 'w', format='NETCDF4')
rainfile = r"H:/NETCDF/Amrie_NC/rain100.csv"
maskfile = r"H:/NETCDF/Amrie_NC/test_a.asc"

rf_loc_data = np.genfromtxt(rainfile,delimiter = ",")[:,1]
rf_dummy_data = np.genfromtxt(rainfile,delimiter = ",")[:,2]
mask_data = np.loadtxt(maskfile,skiprows=6)
mask_data = np.where(mask_data == -99999, 0, mask_data)

time = ds.createDimension('time', None)
lat = ds.createDimension('lat', 2000)
lon = ds.createDimension('lon', 3000)

lats = ds.createVariable('lat', 'float64', ('lat',))
lons = ds.createVariable('lon', 'float64', ('lon',))

#noaa NetCDF file format for lat/lon
lats.units = 'degrees_north'
lats.actual_range = [415000.0000000000000000,435000.0000000000000000]
lats.long_name = 'Latitude'
lats.actual_name = 'latitude'
lats.axis = 'Y'

lons.units = 'degrees_east'
lons.actual_range = [425000.0000000000000000,430000.0000000000000000]
#lons.actual_range = [178.17, 178.20]
lons.long_name = 'Longitude'
lons.actual_name = 'Longitude'
lons.axis = 'X'

lats[:] = np.arange(415000.0000000000000000,435000.0000000000000000, 10)
lons[:] = np.arange(425000.0000000000000000,430000.0000000000000000, 1.667)
#lons[:] = np.arange(178.171277329188, 178.201238, 0.0001066219969935890941)

##create time variables
##https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997314/write-times-in-netcdf-file
calendar = 'standard'
units = 'minutes since 1800-01-01 00:00:0.0'
##https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298054/generating-15-minute-time-interval-array-in-python
times = [datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15*x)
         for x in range(0,len(rf_loc_data))]
timevar32 = ds.createVariable(varname='time', dimensions=('time',),
                              datatype='float64')
#noaa NetCDF file format for time
timevar32.units = units
timevar32.long_name = 'Time'
timevar32.delta_t = '0000-01-00 00:00:00'
timevar32.avg_period = '0000-01-00 00:00:00'#
timevar32.standard_name = 'time'
timevar32.axis = 'T'
timevar32.actual_range = [1569072., 1947432.]

timevar32[:] = nc.date2num(times, units=units, calendar=calendar) 

value = ds.createVariable('percip', 'float32', ('time', 'lat', 'lon',))
value.units = 'mm/hr'
for i in range(0,len(rf_loc_data)):
    rain_val = rf_loc_data[i]
    rain_empty = rf_dummy_data[i]
    rain_apply = np.where(mask_data == 1, rain_val, mask_data)
    rain_split = np.where(rain_apply == 0, rain_empty, rain_apply)
    #rain_split = np.flipud(rain_split)
    value[i, :, :] = rain_apply

crs = ds.createVariable('spatial_ref', 'i4')
crs.spatial_ref='GCS_OSGB_1936",DATUM["D_OSGB_1936",SPHEROID["Airy_1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-100000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-2.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996012717],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'

ds.close()
```